# Daemon Manager for API server

Tags: ubuntu

I have an API server behind a reverse-proxy Apache server. The API server is currently ran as a daemon. I was wondering would there be any daemon managers, just in case my application crashes, that would rerun the server? I've heard of Upstart, but I never had experience with it.

Comment: You can use supervisor. I am using supervisor all the time.

Comment: Upstart is an init system. If that's what your system uses, then use that; or use systemd if that's what's provided. Or use supervisord, or monit, etc.